# jQuery addclass, removeclass and click event problems ( code )

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.isSocial').click(function () {
        var hidden = jQuery('.socialHidden');
        hidden.animate({
            "top": "35px"
        }, 400);
        jQuery(".socialHidden>div").delay(400).animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, 150);
        jQuery(".isSocial").addClass("closejs").removeClass("isSocial");
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.closejs').click(function () {
        var hidden = jQuery('.socialHidden');
        hidden.delay(200).animate({
            "top": "-176px"
        }, 400);
        jQuery(".socialHidden>div").animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 150);
        jQuery(".closejs").addClass("isSocial").removeClass("closejs");
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me fix this code?
The first part works perfectly... When I try to get the second one working, it just does nothing.

This is the html:

```
    <button class="isSocial">BUTTON</button>
    <div class="socialHidden">
    <div>
    content.....
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are changing the classes dynamically, you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on("click", '.isSocial', function () {
        var hidden = jQuery('.socialHidden');
        hidden.animate({
            "top": "35px"
        }, 400);
        jQuery(".socialHidden>div").delay(400).animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, 150);
        jQuery(".isSocial").addClass("closejs").removeClass("isSocial");
        return false;
    });
    jQuery(document).on("click", '.closejs', function () {
        var hidden = jQuery('.socialHidden');
        hidden.delay(200).animate({
            "top": "-176px"
        }, 400);
        jQuery(".socialHidden>div").animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 150);
        jQuery(".closejs").addClass("isSocial").removeClass("closejs");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1. To further expand, whenever you have dynamic elements (elements that are added by the user, or elements that change classes like above), the code that you wrote will not affect those elements, unless you delegate event handlers to parent elements (in this case, `document` is the explicit parent). This is because of the way event bubbling works (goes up then down, or down then up, through the DOM, depending on how you define your event listeners).

Comment: @JoshBeam thats a nice explanaion.